# CakePHP 3 Migrations from Custom Template

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am busy developing a system to manage student's projects as part of my BTech Research Thesis. I want to develop an interface that would help students achieve the following:

- Enter a table name together with its fields. This information is then persisted on the database via a Migrations has many MigrationTableFields.
- On an interval of 30 minutes a cron job would run and create migration files from these tables. This means I will write a console command to do this.

Following a quickstart tutorial (http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/10/20/migrations-cakephp-3-quickstart/) on CakePHP3 Migrations it transpires that I have to add the table name and manually add the fields myself. However, this time around the complete migration file needs to be created by the system itself and automatically pushed to a designated *source control system* thereby alerting the group developers that there have been migration files that have been committed on the source control.

The idea is to separate the roles within a team such that programmers never have to deal with database work they can just checkout their application repository and run their migrations on their dev boxes.

When running the command:

```
./bin/cake migrtions create CreateDriversTable
```

A migration class is created with empty up() and down() methods that needs you to fill up with code.

What I want is to run the same command within a custom shell script like so:

```
exec( $rootCommand . ' create ' . $migrationName . ' --template="' . $templateClass.'"' );
```

Furthermore, I want to be able to pass the table fields that will be collected from MigrationTableFields table and pass them on to the template so that I can have the code below generated automatically for every migration class created by the cron script:

```
public function change()
{

    $table = $this->table('drivers');

    //Columns come from command line passed as parameter and injected onto the template
    $table->addColumn('name', 'string', 'length' => 150)
          ->addColumn('surname', 'string', 'length' => 150)
          ->addColumn('created', 'datetime')
          ->addColumn('modified', 'datetime')
          ->save();

 }
```

At the end of the day the Migration file should be in a complete state no need to fiddle with it to populate the up() and down() method manually everything would be taken care of by my shell script.

Comment: Show us some code. This screams "code this for me".

Comment: @MeetTitan - I have added an update and hope you get the idea I want to run. The $rootCommand would simple be "./bin/cake migrations" for example. Let me know if you need further explanation. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have the solution already figured out, what is the question?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo - I want to create my own custom template from which migration files will be created from. Also when my shell script runs these migrations I want to be able to inject table properties associated with a table from a database and pass them in that template within the same command.

Comment: For example: bin/cake migrations create SampleTable --template="Custom" --fields="blah blah blah something like that". Where do I put my custom template within cakephp? Can I pass table properties in the command to execute? How best can I execute cake commands without using the ShellDispatcher?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating your own bake task and templates. So you can execute `cake bake custom_migration --fields ....` and write the file directly to the migrations folder.

This is the documentation on how to create custom bake tasks:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html

In fact, the migrations plugin takes advantage of the bake extensions to create custom migration templates. Something similar to what you want can be achieved already with the current migrations plugin code:

`cake bake migration CreateUsers id:primary_key name:string created modified`

The shell will understand your arguments and create the right code for you. The valid syntax for the first argument is:

- `Create[Table] column:type antoher_column:type`
- `Drop[Table]`
- `Add[something]To[Table] author_id:integer # adds author_id`
- `Remove[something]From[Table] author_id # removes author_id`